# ForEach Javascript take's only 1st element

Tags: javascript

Hey i've got 4icons and

elements for each of them.
I want to add event listener for icons so when i hover them i will see p element and hide icon.

I can make it like this:

```
    document.getElementById('burger').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    document.getElementById('burgerP').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('burger').style.display = 'none';

})

document.getElementById('burgerP').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    document.getElementById('burgerP').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('burger').style.display = 'block';

})

document.getElementById('food').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    document.getElementById('foodP').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('food').style.display = 'none';

})

document.getElementById('foodP').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    document.getElementById('foodP').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('food').style.display = 'block';

})

document.getElementById('location').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    document.getElementById('locationP').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('location').style.display = 'none';

})

document.getElementById('locationP').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    document.getElementById('locationP').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('location').style.display = 'block';

})

document.getElementById('delivery').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    document.getElementById('deliveryP').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('delivery').style.display = 'none';

})

document.getElementById('deliveryP').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    document.getElementById('deliveryP').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('delivery').style.display = 'block';     
})
```

But i want to make it simple and make it in forEach loop. But when i make it i get effect only on 1st

element. Should i create a node list?
And if so then how? (don't make me code just tell me how to do it please, i want to learn it not copy/paste)

I tried to make it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ikonka').forEach((icon) => {
    icon.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        document.querySelector('.ikonka').style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector('.opis').style.display = "block";
    });
    icon.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
        document.querySelector(".opis").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".ikonka").style.display = "block";
    })
}
)
```

Here's and HTML code:

```
<section id="category">
        <div class="burgers">
            <i class="fas fa-hamburger ikonka" id="burger"></i>
            <p id="burgerP" class="opis">Our burger's!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mainFood">
            <i class="fas fa-utensils ikonka" id="food"></i>
            <p id="foodP" class="opis">Best dishes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="location">
            <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt ikonka" id="location"></i>
            <p id="locationP" class="opis">We are here!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="delivery">
            <i class="fas fa-car ikonka" id="delivery"></i>
            <p id="deliveryP" class="opis">Free Delivery!</p>
        </div>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </section>
```

Comment: You’re using `document.querySelector` in the event listeners again. Use the `icon` variable instead. The call to `document.querySelector` will always select *the first* element on a page matching that selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `icon` inside the callback ... to get the related `.opis` use the undex to get it from the arraylike:

```
const opis = document.querySelectorAll(".opis");
const ikonka = document.querySelectorAll('.ikonka');

 ikonka.forEach((icon, index) => {
   const op = opis[index];
   icon.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
     icon.style.display = "none";
     op.style.display = "block";
   });
   icon.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
     icon.style.display = "none";
     op.style.display = "block";
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a global array containing the IDs (location, delivery,...) of your elements.
Afterwards iterate over this array using a for loop and add the styles to each element you referenced inside.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use `icon` inside the callback ... to get the related
>   `.opis` use the undex to get it from the arraylike:
>
> ```
> const opis = document.querySelectorAll(".opis");
> const ikonka = document.querySelectorAll('.ikonka');
>
>  ikonka.forEach((icon, index) => {
>    const op = opis[index];
>    icon.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
>      icon.style.display = "none";
>      op.style.display = "block";
>    });
>    icon.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
>      icon.style.display = "none";
>      op.style.display = "block";
>    });
> });
> ```

Yes this one work but had to change mouseleave eventlistener for this:

```
const opis = document.querySelectorAll(".opis");
const ikonka = document.querySelectorAll('.ikonka');

 ikonka.forEach((icon, index) => {
   const op = opis[index];
   icon.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
     icon.style.display = "none";
     op.style.display = "block";
   });
   op.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
     icon.style.display = "block";
     op.style.display = "none";
   });
});
```

Because when i enter icon with mouse the P element stay. Now it's okay! thank you :)